# Assign a function to a variable recursively

Tags: function, variables, recursion, return-value, jython-2.7

I've read a lot about that argument here in stackoverflow. Anyway I can't really understand what really happens to a variable when I assign a recursive function to it ! I've tried so hard using printNow() command just to undestand what happening .. but nothing , just a bunch of None !

```
variable = function() #variable is going to be the the return value of function() ?
                      #if function() is a recursive function each time of the recursive, variable
                      #is gonna be different ?
```

edit :
Added a piece of code that i can't understand ..

```
def permute(seq):

  if len(seq)<=1:
    perm=[seq]
  else:
    perm=[]                          
    for i in range(len(seq)):
      sub=permute(seq[:i]+seq[i+1:]) # What sub is gonna be = ? 
      for p in sub:
        perm.append(seq[i:i+1]+p)
```

return perm

Comment: You're never going to understand a concept without having some code.

Comment: Edited the question with a piece of code I can't understand !

Comment: It seems that you have misunderstood the whole concept behind recursive functions. I suggest start with something simple like Factorial.